# Will convict conditioning book help me getting ripped

Tags: bodyweight-exercises, home-exercise, getting-in-shape

I want to know whether this book will help me getting ripped or I'll just gain muscle endurance without mass.
I do want to be gain strength but I also want to be in a good shape and I don't have gyms anywhere near my home so I was advised to read this book as it depends on bodyweight exercises
any thoughts ?

Comment: Someday people will realize that being "ripped" is more about the nutrition than it is the weightlifting.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking about whether book is any good.  Looks Locke it could also be a duplicate

Comment: Maybe change question to explain the workout,  you will get more answers, as not everyone will know of the book

Comment: Hey Peter, I may be able to answer your question, but could you provide some additional detail? I have two main questions. 1) What do you specifically mean by "get ripped"? Are you a skinny guy who wants to put on muscle weight? How much do you weigh, and how much do you want to weigh? 2) What do you want to know that's not in my answer to your other question?